# CSS animation doesn't work properly in IE11

Tags: html, css

I'm using a CSS animation that works fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox but not in IE 11. I can't really find any problem with my code. Could you please tell me where the problem is?

My indicator moves from the 1st item to the last one via click event.

```
<div class="divWrapper">
  <div class="item-indicator move"></div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
             .
             .
             .
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>

.item-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  border-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s;
  right: 100%;
}

.move {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s;
  transition: transform .25s;
  opacity: 1;
  right: auto;
}

.divWrapper [data-position]{
  opacity: 1;
  right: auto;
}

.divWrapper [data-position='1']{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0px); 
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.divWrapper [data-position='2']{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100% + 4px));
  -ms-transform: translateX(calc(100% + 4px));
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 4px));
}

.divWrapper [data-position='3']{
  transform: translateX(calc(200% + 9px));
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is... IE?

Comment: use cross browser prefix like  -ms-

Comment: Go to http://pleeease.io/play/ to generate the correct prefixes.

Comment: i've used prefix, but still have the same problem

Comment: Make a working code snippet so we have with what to work

Answer (score 0):

You can't set transition with only opacity on one class, and transition only with transform on other class (you can but they will override each other).

Try:

```
.item-indicator {
    transition: all .25s;
}

.move {
    /*transition: all .25s; -- not needed like this /*
    transition: opacity .25s, transform .33s;
}
```

Your .move transition was only transitioning transform, and not opacity, because you overided transition property from .item-indicator class.

Comment: @User1979 It is really simple, just set transition: all .25s; to everything and then try...